# What is the difference between cat > filename and cat >> filename in Linux Command Line

Tags: linux, command

I did not had any file initially named "File1.txt" in my `pwd`. I executed the command `cat > File1.txt` in the Linux CLI. It created a new file named "File1.txt" in the pwd. However, the same stuff happened when I wrote the command `cat >> File1.txt`. Is there any real difference between the two commands while using Linux CLI. (I was using Ubuntu while working on CLI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat > a.txt` will overwrite the existing file, where as `cat >> a.txt` will append from last of the file.

Here is an example:

Initially when there is no `a.txt` file

```
> cat a.txt
ls: cannot access 'c.txt': No such file or directory
>
```

Now you create the file with `cat > a.txt` and display it with `cat > a.txt`

```
> cat > a.txt
abcd
^c
> cat a.txt
abcd
>
```

Again if you do the same, it will overwrite it with new content

```
> cat > a.txt
qwer
^c
> cat a.txt
qwer
>
```

But, if you use `cat >> a.txt` command, it will append the new content from the end of the existing file

```
> cat > a.txt
abcd
^c
> cat a.txt
abcd
> cat >> a.txt
qwer
^c
> cat a.txt
abcd
qwer
>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Shubham Jain, if you feel that this clarified you question, please upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: Can I use the cat command to edit the file from somewhere in between ?

Comment: I think no, but not least directly, you have to use other commands.